# Identify book, Three wizards trapped in a city/town

Tags: story-identification, magic, childrens-novel

Trying to find a book I remember reading in the late 90s or early 00s.
The protagonist is a young boy and there are three wizards that are all based at separate sections of a city or large town and are unable to leave those locations.

I remember that one of the wizards is a very large brutish looking man and another is an attractive younger man who is good at charming people, including charming the protagonists’ sister.

I also believe at the end there was a rocket launch as well where at least one of the wizards is trapped inside it as it heads towards space.

Comment: Spaceship? Wizards? This seems a touch anachronous.

Comment: I think the spaceship was basically the same technology wise as was being sent into space at the time so more just like a large rocket, will edit the question to reflect this

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### [*Archer’s Goon*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B008LUVJJ2)

[image]

This novel, by Diana Wynne Jones, was published in 1984, so you certainly could have read it in the late 90s or early 2000s. The protagonist is a young boy.

The book features seven siblings, who could accurately be described as wizards, each of whom “farms” an aspect of a small town’s infrastructure.

> Quentin, at that point, was yelling, "Face the facts, you stupid
>   woman! This town is run by seven megalomaniac wizards!" He blinked at
>   the sudden light and rounded on the Goon. "You!" he bawled. "I hope
>   you’re taking this down in shorthand. I want Archer to know!"

One of these wizards is giant, the titular Goon (shown on the front of the book).

In the end the wizards are sent away in a spaceship:

> Quentin typed a loud full stop and stood up. They all crowded to the
>   window and looked into the yard, where the caretaker still stood,
>   looking suspiciously at the strange moonlit building inside the
>   scaffolding. A wide smile of light appeared in the domed roof, to the
>   right of the great head of Venturus. The smile widened like a moon, to
>   half, then three-quarters, and then to a blaze that struck upward into
>   the blue clouds of the night. There was a gigantic mutter of power, so
>   enormous that the window rattled and everything in the room shook. The
>   girders, and the temple with its opened dome, blurred with it. Their
>   ears went dead. Then, slowly rising from the opened dome, came the
>   spaceship, silvery and stately, up and up, straight as a pencil, into
>   the light of the dome, up out of that light, into the light of the
>   moon, faster and faster and faster. Their eyes followed it up, then
>   up, until its tail spurted white light. A blunt cough of energy came
>   to their dead ears. Against the moon they saw the ship slant sideways
>   and become a shooting star for a second, up and out.

Comment: Thank you this is it. Looks like I forgot a few plot point over the years though...